# Npgsql Minimum Pool Size seems to be not take into account

Tags: .net, postgresql, connection-pooling, npgsql

In my .Net application (that runs on multiple pods) I'm using following connection string:

```
"User ID=;Password=;Host=;Port=;Database=;Pooling=true;Username=;ApplicationName=;Max Auto Prepare=200;Minimum Pool Size=90;Maximum Pool Size=100;Read Buffer Size=18000;Timeout=1;Command Timeout=5;"
```

(I know that `Minimum Pool Size=90` is little too high, but it's just to tackle the issue)

Having the above I am expecting that each pod will have between **90** and **100** active connections to the DB server. However, when I execute following query:

`select client_addr, count(*) used FROM pg_stat_activity where datname = 'my_app_name' group by client_addr;`

results shows that each pod has max around ~30 connections.

[image: connections per client_addr count]

This is how I use connections and execute queries in my C# code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetGeneric<T>(string query, DynamicParameters parameters)
{
    await using var connection = DbConnectionHelper.Create(myConnectionString);
    return await connection.QueryAsync<T>(query, parameters);
}
```

###### DbConnectionHelper:

```
public static class DbConnectionHelper
{
    public static NpgsqlConnection Create(string connectionString)
    {
        var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

From this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling#adding-connections) I can read:

> When a pool is created, multiple connection objects are created and added to the pool so that the minimum pool size requirement is satisfied.

Meaning **90** connections per each pod should be added on app start. Shouldn't it?

This rises following questions:

1. Why `Minimum Pool Size` is not used?
2. Why I don't see numbers between 90 and 100 when executing `select client_addr, count(*) used FROM pg_stat_activity` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you are referring to is not the one for `npgsql` and doesn't apply.

While the [doc](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#pooling) for `npgsql` isn't very verbose on the `Minimum Pool Size`, we can look at the code and find that

1. there is no reference to opening several connections at startup
2. connections are [closed](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/d1e791091e330396d50520d627cc54808c5d6b78/src/Npgsql/PoolingDataSource.cs#L249) only if there are more than `Minimum Pool Size`

So the answer is that your clients haven't needed the 90 concurrent connections so they are not open yet.